# Is there away to access whats inside a function with an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, random, onclick

**So, I want to know if its possible to access whats inside a function and use it on an onClick event.

For example:

```
   function random(){
       Math.floor(Math.random()*2+1)
   }
```

And my question is;  I want to use the If statement for whats inside the function.

```
    if(random number ===1) do something on onClick event.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `return` keyword to state what the value of a function is:

```
function random(){
   return Math.floor(Math.random()*2+1)
}
```

Then, other code can access the value by doing: `random()`.  For example:

```
if(random() == 1){
   // Random is 1
} else {
   // Random is not 1
}
```